# JavaMail API: Checking the size limit of the server

Tags: java, email, size, jakarta-mail

Is there any way to check the e-mail size limit of the server you're using to send your e-mail with? I doubt there'd be a way to check the one you're sending to (but if there is a way I'd love to hear about that too). I'm guessing this could depend on the server you're using, so I'll ask specifically for Google Apps/Gmail servers just so I can get the gist. Any other pointers would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP allows the server to report the maximum message size it allows.  Not all servers do.  [This thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2364840&tstart=0) has more details.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience - no. Every server has its own restrictions and there is no way to detect it automatically with JavaMail Api.

My work around: I create a Map server - limit in properties file and use it when sending mail from user. You can go to every server and define it from site. If no server was found in my map I use default restrictions.

And also there was no standard notification about limit excead. I mean Exception when sending file that excead limit.